# exam/tcolorbx: Calculate the header height then pass it to geometry

Tags: header-footer, tcolorbox, boxes, geometry, exam

For the following, I need to make the two approaches work in order to pass the exact header height to `geometry` package.

I would be happy if other approaches are proposed.

### Using savebox

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster]{tcolorbox}

\newsavebox{\headerbox}
\newcommand{\TCheader}{%
    \savebox{\headerbox}% 
    {%
        \begin{tcbraster}[
            raster columns=3, raster rows=1, valign=center,
            raster height = 2cm, raster column skip = 0mm
            ]
            \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0pt,right=0pt]
                First line\\ Second Line
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center]
                Centered Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=right]
                \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{tcbraster}%
    }%
}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\firstpageheader{}{\TCheader}{}

\usepackage[
includehead, 
top = 10 mm,
headheight =  \the\ht\headerbox
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
text
\usebox\headerbox
\end{document}
```

---

### Using settoheight

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\Anotherheader}{%
    \settoheight{\headerheight}% 
    {%
        \begin{tcbraster}[
            raster columns=3, raster rows=1, valign=center,
            raster height = 2cm, raster column skip = 0mm
            ]
            \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0pt,right=0pt]
                First line\\ Second Line
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center]
                Centered Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=right]
                \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{tcbraster}%
    }%
}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\firstpageheader{}{\Anotherheader}{}

\usepackage[
includehead, 
top = 10 mm,
headheight =  \headerheight
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would lose the \TCBheader command.  You can set a savebox in the preamble, and use \firstpageheader{}{\usebox\headerboxr}{}.  Note that \settoheight uses a savebox internally, so you aren't saving anything (except the box register).  Also, you could probably use \smash{...} in the header and not worry about the height.

Comment: It seems that `tcbraster` cannot be saved into a box in preamble.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I would be grateful if you could provide an answer to show me what you mean.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Additionally, how can I retrieve the depth when using `settoheight`?

Comment: There is also \settodepth, but that is partly why a savebox is better and faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `tcbraster` needs some envelope as a `minipage` to be put into a box.

For your applications, I would use `tcboxedraster` which is a raster inside a `tcolorbox` which can be saved for later.

IMHO, the height has not to be computed, because the height is already know (`2cm`).

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster,skins]{tcolorbox}

\def\headerContents{%
  \begin{tcboxedraster}[
      raster columns=3, raster rows=1, valign=center,
      raster height = 2cm, raster column skip = 0mm
      ]{blankest, nobeforeafter, baseline=\baselineskip, enlarge bottom finally by=-0.4pt}
      \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0pt,right=0pt]
          First line\\ Second Line
      \end{tcolorbox}
      \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center]
          Centered Text
      \end{tcolorbox}
      \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=right]
          \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
      \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{tcboxedraster}%
}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{}{\headerContents}{}

\usepackage[
  includehead,
  top = 0mm, % 0mm is just for test
  %headheight = \headerTotalHeight,
  headheight = 2cm,
  showframe % draw frames to show page layout
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Some explanations to the code above:

- `baseline=\baselineskip` is used to lower the `tikzpicture` under the baseline. `\baselineskip` is more than enough (may be replaced by something better), but does the job here.
- `enlarge bottom finally by=-0.4pt` is just fine-tuning to overwrite the header line which has a thickness of `0.4pt`. This gives a perfect fit to the upper page edge.

Comment: 2cm is an example not my real problem, so it is not always easy for me every time to calculate. I will experiment with your answer to better understand it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Directly saving `tcbraster` environment into box in preamble raises `Missing \begin{document}` error, caused by the `\noindent` at the end of `\begin{tcbraster}`. Hence I wrap `tcbraster` into a `minipage` environment. The `\settototalheight` from `calc` package is also used.

This works but I'm afraid it is not the perfect solution.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\headerContents{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns=3, raster rows=1, valign=center,
        raster height = 2cm, raster column skip = 0mm
        ]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0pt,right=0pt]
            First line\\ Second Line
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center]
            Centered Text
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=right]
            \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\newlength{\headerTotalHeight}
\settototalheight\headerTotalHeight{\headerContents}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{}{\headerContents}{}

\usepackage[
  includehead, 
  top = 0mm, % 0mm is just for test
  headheight = \headerTotalHeight,
  showframe % draw frames to show page layout
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, compile your answer again with the following options of `geometry`:

`\usepackage[
a4paper,
includehead,
top = 0 mm,
headheight = \ht\headerbox,
showframe
]{geometry}`. You will notice that the header overflows the allocated space as shown [here](https://i.ibb.co/PmWLs7H/image.png).

Comment: I think you need to make it like this `headheight = \dimexpr \ht\headerbox + \dp\headerbox,` in order to work as expected.

Comment: @JohnKormylo where should it be written?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Then the `\leavevmode` inside `\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox` raises the same error.

Comment: @Diaa Answer updated. It should work now.

Comment: May I know why would you choose `\def` over `\newcommand`?

Comment: Alas, \setbox\headerbox-\vbox{...} doesn't work either.  Weird!

Comment: @Diaa `\newcommand` is more recommended here since it checks naming crash. Answer updated.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could take a look at my follow-up question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572700/2288.

Answer (score 2):

Note that loading geometry changes `\textwidth`, so I load it immediately then use `\geometry` to set the final dimensions.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% affects \textwidth
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster]{tcolorbox}

\newsavebox\headerbox

\savebox{\headerbox}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns=3, raster rows=1, valign=center,
        raster height = 2cm, raster column skip = 0mm
        ]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0pt,right=0pt]
            First line\\ Second Line
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center]
            Centered Text
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=right]
            \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}%
  \end{minipage}%
}
\geometry{includehead, top = 10 mm, headheight={\dimexpr \ht\headerbox+\dp\headerbox}}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{}{\usebox\headerbox}{}

\begin{document}
text

\noindent\usebox\headerbox
\end{document}
```