# tcolorbox: error with \settototalheight when calculating the header height before passing it to the geometry package

Tags: header-footer, tcolorbox, geometry, exam, calculations

Following up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547859/2288), I would like to know why the following doesn't compile and gives this error

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \tcb@startbox ...x }{\tcb@w@upper }\tcb@lua@color
> {tcbcolupper}\kvtcb@fontup...

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\exProgram}{3\textsuperscript{rd} Year}
\newcommand{\CourseName}{Engineering}
\newcommand*{\CourseCode}{311}
\newcommand*{\exMidFinal}{Midterm}
\newcommand*{\exSemester}{Fall}

\newcommand\headerBody{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        raster multicolumn = 3
        ]
        \begin{tcbitemize}[
            raster force size=false,
            raster columns=2,
            valign=bottom,
            raster equal skip = 0mm,
            blankest,
            ]
            \tcbitem[add to width = 2cm, halign = left,]
            University\\ Faculty\\
            \exProgram
            \tcbitem[add to width =-2cm, halign = right]  \includegraphics[height=20 mm]{example-image}
        \end{tcbitemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    %
    \vspace{5pt}\hrule\vspace{5pt}%
    %
    \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0pt,right=0pt]
        \exMidFinal\\
        \exSemester
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[before upper*=\centering]
        Course Code: \textbf{\CourseCode}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=right]
        1\\
        2
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    %
    \vspace{5pt}\hrule\vspace{5pt}%
    %
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        before upper*=\centering, equal height group=A,
        interior engine = standard,
        colback = gray,
        raster multicolumn = 3,
        top = 5pt, bottom = 5pt
        ]
        \textbf{\CourseName}
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    %
    \vspace{5pt}\hrule\vspace{5pt}%
    %
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        before upper*=\centering,
        equal height group=A,
        raster multicolumn = 3,
        ]
        This exam contains
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newcommand\headerContents{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
        \begin{tcbraster}[
            raster columns=3, raster rows=3,
            raster equal height = rows,
            raster every box/.style={minimum for current equal height group = 8 mm},
            valign=center,
            raster equal skip = 0mm,
            top = 0mm, bottom = 0mm,
            blankest,
            nobeforeafter,
            ]
            \headerBody%
            \vspace*{5pt}%
            \hrule%
        \end{tcbraster}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\newlength{\headerTotalHeight}
\settototalheight\headerTotalHeight{\headerContents}


\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{}{\headerContents}{}

\usepackage[
a4paper,
includehead,
top = 0mm,
headheight = \headerTotalHeight,
showframe
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

Comment: you shouldn't look only at the error as presented by your editor (texstudio?), they often shorten it and don't show the actual undefined command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the hint. I remember you previously told me about some package or way to quote the errors but I don't remember it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never measure things in the preamble. Font settings might be delayed at begin document.

Do the setting at the right place:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\settototalheight\headerTotalHeight{\headerContents}}
```

---

Now, if you want to know why this used to run but now fails? A change in `tcolorbox.sty`, aimed at exploiting LuaTeX color management if available, has been introduced. This requires defining `\tcb@lua@color` in a suitable way and the package author chose to do it at begin document.

This means that the meaning of `\tcb@lua@color` is not yet available in the document preamble, whence the error.

Comment: Now, it works, but the header is printed above the paper top border. What should be done to make it printed as expected just below the paper top border?

Comment: So, I think `\headerTotalHeight` was passed to `geometry` too late.

Comment: add `\geometry{headheight = \headerTotalHeight}` to the \AtBeginDocument command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would be grateful if you could provide me with a full-code answer to make sure I do it right.

Comment: If I would like to have the following `\newlength{\headerTotalHeight}
\AtBeginDocument{\settototalheight\headerTotalHeight{\headerContents}\geometry{headheight = \headerTotalHeight}}` inside the `\ExplSyntax` code of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573233/2288), what should be done?

Comment: Additionally, I found that your solution works great for only the header. However, the first page footer is unknowingly badly displaced as shown in my follow-up question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573380/2288.