# exam/geometry: First footer is shifted below when setting geometry using \AtBeginDocument

Tags: header-footer, geometry, exam, calculations, etoolbox

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572702/2288) does the job for placing the header right. However, the **first** footer is unknowingly shifted way much down.

So, why does `\AtBeginDocument{\settototalheight\headerTotalHeight{\headerContents}\geometry{headheight = \headerTotalHeight}}` affect the first footer?

### Footer at the first page

[image]

### Footer at the following pages

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\headerContents{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
}

\newlength{\headerTotalHeight} 
\AtBeginDocument{\settototalheight\headerTotalHeight{\headerContents}\geometry{headheight = \headerTotalHeight}}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{}{\headerContents}{}
\runningheader{}{\headerContents}{}
\firstpagefooter{}{first footer}{}
\runningfooter{}{running footer}{}

\usepackage[
a4paper,
includehead,
top = 0mm,
includefoot,
foot = 0 em,
bottom = 4 em,
showframe
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    text
    \newpage
    text
\end{document}
```