# Exam layout with geometry and tcolorbox

Tags: header-footer, tcolorbox, geometry, exam

Here are several questions:

1- How to make the usage of `\tcboxfit` in the first raster row not distort the layout as shown below?

[image]

2- How to precisely calculate the dimensions summation passed to `headheight` option of `geometry`  so that the header starts exactly at the page top border?

3- Why doesn't `\iflastpage{\enlargethispage{-1cm}}{}` work inside `\NewDocumentCommand{\FillAnswerRules}` to make a room for the `End of the Exam` text?

[image]

4- Why is not the space (nearly of `\baselineskip`) between the header and the mainstream text eliminated despite setting `headsep = 0pt`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[fontsize = 14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster,skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\newcommand{\myfooter}{%
    \iflastpage{\raisebox{5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\large End of the Exam}}{}%
    \hrule\vspace{5pt}%
    Instructors%
}

\newcommand\headerBody{%
    \begin{tcbitemize}[
        raster valign = bottom,
        valign = bottom,
        raster columns = 2,
        blankest,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        ]
        \tcboxfit[height = 3em, add to width = 2cm, halign = flush left,height=3em] University\\Faculty\\Program
        \tcbitem[add to width = -2cm, halign = flush right,] \includegraphics[height = 3em]{example-image}
    \end{tcbitemize}
    %
    \hrule
    %
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 3,
        valign = center,
        raster before skip = 1ex,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest
        ]
        \tcboxfit{Final\\Semester}
        \tcboxfit[before upper*=\centering]{Course Code}
        \tcboxfit[halign = flush right]{\textbf{date}\\\textbf{time}}
    \end{tcbraster}
    %
    \hrule
    %
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 1,
        valign = center, halign = flush center, 
        raster before skip = 1ex,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest
        ]
        \tcboxfit[interior engine = standard,colback = gray!20, top = 1ex, bottom = 1ex,]{\textbf{Course}}%
    \end{tcbraster}
    %
    \hrule
    %
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 1,
        valign = center, halign = flush center,
        raster before skip = 1ex,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest,
        ]
        \tcboxfit[top = 1ex, bottom = 1ex,]{This exam contains.}%
    \end{tcbraster}
    %
    \hrule%
}

\newcommand\headerContents{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547910/2288 
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        fit algorithm=hybrid*,
        raster equal height = rows,
        raster halign = center, raster valign = center,
        raster equal skip = 0mm,
        raster force size = false,
        boxsep = 0pt,
        beforeafter skip = 0pt, 
        leftright skip = 0pt,
        raster right skip = 0pt,
        raster left skip = 0pt,
        raster before skip = 0pt,
        raster after skip = 0pt,
        nobeforeafter,
        height = 2em,
        raster rows=4,
        ]%
        \headerBody%
    \end{tcbraster}%
}


\firstpageheader{}{\headerContents}{}
\runningheader{}{\headerContents}{}

\firstpagefooter{}{\myfooter}{}
\runningfooter{}{\myfooter}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { diaa / answers }
{
    d .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim,
    t .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim,
    c .tl_set:N  = \l__diaa_answers_color_tl,
    d .initial:n = 10mm,
    t .initial:n = 0.2pt,
    c .initial:n = gray,
}

\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} }
{
    height~fill, text~fill, colback=white, boxrule=2pt, sharp~corners,
    boxsep=0pt, left=10pt, right=10pt, top=8pt, bottom=0pt, #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FillAnswerRules}{O{}}
{
    \iflastpage{\enlargethispage{-1cm}}{}
    \begin{fillAnswerRules}
        \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }
        \leaders \hbox:n
        {
            \makebox[\textwidth][s]
            {
                \color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}
                \vrule width 0pt height 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                depth 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                \leaders \hrule height \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim \hfill
            }
        }\vfill
        \null
    \end{fillAnswerRules}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[
a4paper,
includehead, 
headsep=0pt,
includefoot, 
foot=0mm, 
bottom=20mm,
headheight = \dimexpr9em+9ex+0pt,
top=0mm,
showframe
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question 
        \begin{parts}
            \part \lipsum[1-2]
                \FillAnswerRules
                \FillAnswerRules
                
            \part \lipsum[1]
                \FillAnswerRules
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119170/discussion-on-question-by-diaa-exam-layout-with-geometry-and-tcolorbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution puts the header into a savebox in order to the compute header height accurately.  It also increments the page counter before `\iflastpage` inside `\FillAnswerRules`.

Note that `\tcb@startbox` etc. are not defined until `\AtBeginDocument`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[fontsize = 14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster,skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\newcommand{\myfooter}{%
    \iflastpage{\raisebox{\dimexpr \height+\depth+5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\large End of the Exam}}{}%
    \hrule\vspace{5pt}%
    Instructors%
}

\newcommand\headerBody{%
    \begin{tcbitemize}[
        raster valign = bottom,
        valign = bottom,
        raster columns = 2,
        blankest,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        ]
        \tcboxfit[height = 3em, add to width = 2cm, halign = flush left,height=3em] {University\\Faculty\\Program}
        \tcbitem[add to width = -2cm, halign = flush right,] \includegraphics[height = 3em]{example-image}
    \end{tcbitemize}
    %
    \hrule
    %
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 3,
        valign = center,
        raster before skip = 1ex,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest
        ]
        \tcboxfit{Final\\Semester}
        \tcboxfit[before upper*=\centering]{Course Code}
        \tcboxfit[halign = flush right]{\textbf{date}\\\textbf{time}}
    \end{tcbraster}
    %
    \hrule
    %
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 1,
        valign = center, halign = flush center, 
        raster before skip = 1ex,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest
        ]
        \tcboxfit[interior engine = standard,colback = gray!20, top = 1ex, bottom = 1ex,]{\textbf{Course}}%
    \end{tcbraster}
    %
    \hrule
    %
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 1,
        valign = center, halign = flush center,
        raster before skip = 1ex,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest,
        ]
        \tcboxfit[top = 1ex, bottom = 1ex,]{This exam contains.}%
    \end{tcbraster}
    %
    \hrule%
}

\usepackage[a4paper,
includehead, 
headheight=0pt,% will be reset \AtBeginDocument
headsep=0pt,
includefoot, 
foot=0mm, 
bottom=20mm,
top=0mm,
showframe]{geometry}

\newsavebox{\headerbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\savebox{\headerbox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        fit algorithm=hybrid*,
        raster equal height = rows,
        raster halign = center, raster valign = center,
        raster equal skip = 0mm,
        raster force size = false,
        boxsep = 0pt,
        beforeafter skip = 0pt, 
        leftright skip = 0pt,
        raster right skip = 0pt,
        raster left skip = 0pt,
        raster before skip = 0pt,
        raster after skip = 0pt,
        nobeforeafter,
        height = 2em,
        raster rows=4,
        ]%
        \headerBody%
    \end{tcbraster}%
\end{minipage}}

\geometry{headheight = {\dimexpr \ht\headerbox+\dp\headerbox}}
\enlargethispage{-\headheight}% first page only
}% end of \AtBeginDocument

\firstpageheader{}{\usebox\headerbox}{}
\runningheader{}{\usebox\headerbox}{}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put({\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin},{\dimexpr 20mm-\paperheight-\baselineskip})%
  {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering\myfooter}}}% first page footer
%\firstpagefooter{}{\myfooter}{}
\runningfooter{}{\myfooter}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { diaa / answers }
{
    d .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim,
    t .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim,
    c .tl_set:N  = \l__diaa_answers_color_tl,
    d .initial:n = 10mm,
    t .initial:n = 0.2pt,
    c .initial:n = gray,
}

\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} }
{
    height~fill, text~fill, colback=white, boxrule=2pt, sharp~corners,
    boxsep=0pt, left=10pt, right=10pt, top=8pt, bottom=0pt, #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FillAnswerRules}{O{}}
{\stepcounter{page}\iflastpage{\enlargethispage{-1cm}}{}\addtocounter{page}{-1}% does not affect footer location
        \begin{fillAnswerRules}
        \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }
        \leaders \hbox:n
        {
            \makebox[\textwidth][s]
            {
                \color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}
                \vrule width 0pt height 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                depth 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                \leaders \hrule height \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim \hfill
            }
        }\vfill
        \null
    \end{fillAnswerRules}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question 
        \begin{parts}
            \part \lipsum[1-2]
                \FillAnswerRules
                \FillAnswerRules

            \part \lipsum[1]
                \FillAnswerRules
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: When running your answer using lualatex, I get this error: `Undefined control sequence.
\tcb@startbox ...x }{\tcb@w@upper }\tcb@lua@color 
                                                  {tcbcolupper}\kvtcb@fontup...
l.89 \end{minipage}}`

Comment: I revised the solution.

Comment: Would you please help me understand: (1) what `\height` and `\depth` mean inside the definition of footer; where did they come from? (2) what does this trick do `{\stepcounter{page}\iflastpage{\enlargethispage{-1cm}}{}\addtocounter{page}{-1}`? (3) what made the gap below the header disappeared in your code? or what made it show up in my code?

Comment: \baselineskip depends on the font size, which is different inside the \raisebox than outside.  So I used \height+\depth instead.  They are computed by \raisebox based on the contents.  Unlike most document classes, exam class does not increment the page counter until **after** the text area is formatted (before the footer is added), so the value will not match \iflastpage.  I set \headheight to precisely the value needed to fit the header (\headerbox), rather than attempting to make the header match \headheight.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Also, why did you need to use `minipage` with the box? In other words, what makes the header has extra space below without `minipage`?

Comment: In the last version of your answer, you will notice that the footer of the first page is pushed aggressively outside the page bottom edge. Can it be fixed?

Comment: You can lose the minipage.  Exam class puts the footer below \footskip instead of on it (baseline).

Comment: I am sorry but I would be grateful if you could help me fix this issue of the first page footer since I don't know how to do so.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to fix the first page footer, so I replaced it.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Out of curiosity, is it possible to make first page footer have the same skip of the running pages? Since this is the first page https://i.ibb.co/6Zc46RB/image.png and this is the second https://i.ibb.co/f4C2P3L/image.png. You can notice a slight bigger skip for the first page footer.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, where does `1in` in the horizontal position of the first-page-footer come from?

Comment: Furthermore, having `Instructors\\Instructors\\Instructors` in the footer leads to this https://i.ibb.co/GvTKt3C/image.png in the first page

Comment: The 1in is the built in margin from TeX (for backward compatibility).  I forgot to add the [t] option to \parbox, and since I can't find the code exam class uses to implement footers, I had to guess at the offset.  Try replacing the \baselineskip in the \put with other values until it matches.

Comment: Another way to get them all the same height is to replace \ThisHookNext with \AddToHook and set the default footer to blank.